# Node.js & Express : No answer if server is running

Tags: node.js, express

I'm currently having a problem while learning to use Node.js and Express to create a server.
Trying to realize a simple request/answer thing, I created the following code :

file server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var jry = require('./journey');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/NewPath', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text-plain');
    jry.createPath(res);
    res.status(200);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text-plain');
    res.write('No page selected');
    res.status(200);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

file journey.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');

module.exports = {
    createPath: function(res) {
        res.write('This is a test');

    }
}
```

However, when I try to launch the server (Using "node server.js"), and access to http://localhost:8080/, the page keeps loading forever.
Stopping the server with CTRL+C instantly finish the page, which displays the correct information.

This doesn't seems to be a problem of my installation : Using example code of Express works without any problem.

Thanks a lot for yuor answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `res.end()` when you have finished doing things with that particular response.

In particular, you might want to add this line to the end of your server.js request handlers, after possible calls to `jry.createPath` and `res.write()`